# Should we allow questions about commonly used gaming terminology?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

For example, this question: [What does the term "carebear" mean in Eve Online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/741/what-does-the-term-carebear-mean-in-eve-online), or a hypothetical question about what "gg" means. Do they fall under this site's purview?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jeff has stated - in the context of other sites - that "there is no such thing as a stupid question". And like they say on "Who Wants To Be A Millionaire" a question's only easy if you know the answer.

Someone who is new to a game won't know the "common" terminology, especially if it's used by everyone else with little or no context. So rather than showing yourself up as a complete noob on the game you need to ask the question somewhere else.

Here would seem a good place.

Answer (score 5):

Why not? These are concrete questions that are not really subjective and are very answerable - most likely they can all have a "most correct single answer".

And it's very gaming related, obviously.

Comment: All these points are good, but I want to bring attention to the last point, which I find the most important thing for asking these questions on this site - being game related. "GG" narrowly skirts about this one, as it technically is game-related. However, we'd have to be careful about ending up as a lexicon for all manner of netspeak used by people in gaming communities, regardless of whether the terms are actually related to gaming. Not saying that we will become one, but saying we should be observant.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the term being discussed. Some definitions are very clear (What is frag in FPS?) but some terms might be considered subjective.
 For example I strongly disagree with [the second definition of carebear on UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=CareBear) (the one about Eve-Online)